# Odd sharing access violation (OS Error 32) with Freepascal implementation of libEWF

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

I am hoping to implement the workings of a C library called [libEWF](https://github.com/libyal/libewf) (by Joachim Metz) into my Freepascal program. A chap called Erwan has already converted an earlier version of the [library to Delphi](http://labalec.fr/erwan/?tag=ewfdelphilibewf) early last year sometime, which I have an in turn tweaked a little for use with Freepascal.

My problem relates to [OS Error code 32 'access sharing violation'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx) which is returned by the following code and suggests there is a problem with accessing the output file (which is created as a zero byte file but nothing is ever written to it).

```
uses
LibEWFUnit, Windows, ....  
// Image\backup disk using EWF image format, return bytes imaged
function WindowsImageDiskEWF(hDiskHandle : THandle; DiskSize : Int64) : Int64;
var
  Buffer  : array [0..32767] of Byte; 
  fLibEWF : TLibEWF;

begin

  // Initilise the libEWF instance
  fLibEWF:=TLibEWF.create;
  fLibEWF.libewf_SetCompressionValues(1,0);
  fLibEWF.libewf_SetHeaderValue('acquiry_software_version','YAFFI');

  // Create and open the output file, .e.g MyImage.E01 with write access      
  if fLibEWF.libewf_open(frmYaffi.ledtImageName.Text,LIBEWF_OPEN_WRITE)=0 then
  begin
  try      
  // Now to seek to start of device
   FileSeek(hDiskHandle, 0, 0);
     repeat
       // Read source device handle in buffered segments. 
       BytesRead     := FileRead(hDiskHandle, Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer));
       if BytesRead = -1 then
         begin
           RaiseLastOSError;
           exit;
         end;
       inc(TotalBytesRead, BytesRead);

       // Now write buffer to libEWF instance, but -1 keeps being returned
       BytesWritten  := fLibEWF.libewf_write_random(@Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), TotalBytesRead);         
       if BytesWritten = -1 then
         begin
           RaiseLastOSError;  //THIS KEEPS BEING RAISED : OS ERROR 32
           exit;
         end;          
       inc(TotalBytesWritten, BytesWritten);
   .....
   finally
     fLibEWF.libewf_close;
   ..... 
  end;
end;
```

and on it is supposed to go until TotalBytesRead equals the size of the input device.

However, as the notes show, for some reason, -1 is always being returned by

```
BytesWritten  := fLibEWF.libewf_write_random(@Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), BytesRead);
```

and RaiseLastOSError keeps generating OS error code 32 - access sharing violation. Using [UnlockIT](http://emcosoftware.com/unlock-it) to check if anything else has a hold on the image file file, it shows only my prgram does. Same goes for the DLL file that comes with the converted library that Erwan supplies.

I have tried contacting Erwan to see if he can help (as he manages to create E01 backup files with his utility [CloneDisk](http://labalec.fr/erwan/?cat=26) which uses this same library but with Delphi) but an answer has not arrived yet and may never do. So I am hoping someone can offer me guidance on how to resolve this? Joachim Metz has been good enough to reply to me but he clearly has many projects on but despite that he was good enough to tell me that the sharing rights are assigned by [this other library, line 505 of libcfile_file.c](https://github.com/libyal/libcfile/blob/master/libcfile/libcfile_file.c#L505). But as my unit is from an earlier version of libEWF that was then converted to Delphi and then to Freepascal, I don't think I can use or rely on that.

The converted Delphi unit that I have tweaked for use with Freepascal is visible [HERE](https://github.com/tedsmith/yaffi/blob/master/ewfacquireForFPCAPI/LibEWFUnit.pas). It is line 301 of that file that makes result = -1 which is how BytesWritten subsequently becomes equal to -1 and therefore fails. If anyone can see what changes I need to make, I'd be obliged.

And before anyone says "just convert the C library to a pascal unit", can I suggest you try to do that before suggesting it! If it was that easy, I'd download the latest and most recent master from https://github.com/libyal/libewf and create a new, fresh DLL and unit with all the modernisations. But I've spent three days battling with that concept and been met with nothing but failure.So Erwans Delphi unit is the best hope I have. Thanks

Comment: BytesRead is -1 after the read. Why don't you check for errors after reading. You call GetLastError way too late.

Comment: BytesWritten is -1, not BytesRead. BytesRead is fine.

Comment: You check BytesRead after writing! And again, you call GetLastError way too late. I'd just compile the C code that works.

Comment: Question adjusted to reflect your recommendation which I have implemented and tried last night. The same error still occurs but you're right about the structure. Thanks

Comment: You are still calling `GetLastError` too late. You call `libewf_close` before you call `GetLastError`.

Comment: I mean, I don't believe that is your problem, but we may as well be 100% sure we are getting the right information.

Comment: I quite agree. Changes made and as you predicted, the sharing violation persists. But it's good to get the ducks in order. I appreciate the tutorlidge.

Comment: You need to handle the call to `libewf_close` differently. Presumably you must call it if `libewf_open` succeeds. In that case, add a Try/Finally block inside the `if` statement. As the very first thing inside that `if`. Put the call to `libewf_close` in the finally section. So even if you raise OS errors, the call to `libewf_close` will be made.

Comment: Done. Question adjusted. Problem still arises but as you say, cleaner to close it in the finally as this will ensure closure regardless of whether of the process succeeds or fails.

Comment: A friend over at Lazarus forums has run my code on his Windows XP 32 platform, and it worked for him! So this is something specific to either CPU architecture (64-bit) or Windows Vista\7\8 versions.

Comment: You don't know that for sure.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm tempted to put the `delphi` and `error-handling` tags back in... the question is specifically in reference to a Delphi library and the entire problem centres around error handling.

Answer (score 3):

`RaiseLastOSError` is probably not even relevant here.  In Erwan's Delphi implementation the call to `libewf_write_random` looks like :

```
function TLibEWF.libewf_write_random(buffer : pointer; 
                                     size : longword; 
                                     offset : int64) : integer;
var
  err:pointer;
begin
  err:=nil;
  Result:=-1;
  if fLibHandle<>0 then begin
    if LIBEWF_VERSION='V1' then 
      Result:=fLibEWFWriteRand(fCurEWFHandle, buffer, size, offset);
    if LIBEWF_VERSION='V2' then 
      Result:=flibewfhandlewriterandom(fCurEWFHandle, buffer, size, offset,@err);
  end;
end;
```

Since version `V2` is most likely current and you are most likely using version 2, and since version 2 provides error information, this Delphi implementation is hiding the error information returned by LibEWF.  There is extensive error checking and handling [in the C library](https://github.com/libyal/libewf/blob/master/libewf/libewf_handle.c).  The method signature for this write method resolves to :

```c
 ssize_t libewf_handle_write_buffer(libewf_handle_t *handle,
                                    const void *buffer,
                                    size_t buffer_size,
                                    libcerror_error_t **error )
```

where the `error` argument is a pointer to a structure ([standard libcerror structure](https://github.com/libyal/libcerror)) that contains the detailed error information that would assist your debugging. For example, one of dozens of such calls in `libewf_handle_write_buffer` :

```c
if( internal_handle->current_offset < 0 )
{
    libcerror_error_set(
     error,               
     LIBCERROR_ERROR_DOMAIN_RUNTIME,
     LIBCERROR_RUNTIME_ERROR_VALUE_OUT_OF_BOUNDS,
     "%s: invalid handle - invalid IO handle - current offset value out of bounds.",
     function );

    return( -1 );
}
```

In all cases where `libewf_write_random` returns -1 the underlying library call also returns error information. This is the error information you need to be checking.  There seems no way to do this with the current Delphi implementation you are using.  I would strongly suggest that you write your own wrapper for the LibEWF DLL, or modify the one you have, such that it retrieves this error information. This will tell you where the real problem lies. Surely the error is not an `I/O 32` error.

Comment: Perhaps I was naive in assuming that the error handling in the question was accurate. Oh well. +1

Comment: OK. MAny thanks for the pointers. I fear that this is another frustrating example of something that I would like to do but which is beyond my skill and ability. Re-wrapping C libraries as Freepascal units has not historically worked well for me. I spent 3 nights trying with this using h2pas and got nowhere really. But both you and David have said the same so maybe that is the reality I must face.

Comment: @Gizmo_the_Great You wouldn't have to re-write from scratch.  The existing pascal method already has the error structure pointer in it - you just need to extend that method to read the values and return them.  You wouldn't necessarily even have to convert the entire `libcerror` structure if that seems too daunting.  Just define a record with two integers and cast the error to a pointer to that type - that should let you read the first two `int`s returned and convert them to the appropriate error : https://github.com/libyal/libewf/blob/master/include/libewf/error.h

Comment: I second what @J... says. I would also add that in my experience, automatic header translation tools are a waste of time. Don't even attempt to use them.